# Mouse cursor replacement in Windows

Tags: winapi, mouse-cursor

Is it possible to replace default mouse cursor with some more complex animated object that has size bigger than 32x32?

I know that I can use transparent window instead of cursor, but it doesn't look as good solution because cursor renders much more faster than window, therefore user could see movement delays.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

32x32 is the maximum size for a cursor on Windows, as far as I know.